# First time visitor can't see my site

Tags: apache, webserver

**PROBLEM**

Visitors that come up to my [site](http://labmais.com.br) for the first time see an error as it didn't exist.

It's weird and makes no sense to me, as I can see and browse it properly. And never seen anything similar.

**REPORTED BY GOOGLE BUSINESS**

It was pointed out by the sales team of Google My Business. They were attempting to sell me some service but reported they were not getting into my site.

**TESTS**

I just tested my site at two different services ([Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/bjOxaf/www.labmais.com.br) and [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/)) in order to ensure that this "1st time visitor" problem was real.
And it seemed to confirm it.

It doesn't make any sense for me; I'm pretty much lost.

Comment: If the app that runs on this domain relies on a cookie or session that doesn't exist for first time visitor, yes, it will fail.

Comment: @Capsule, how can I determine this scenario?

Comment: I don't know, by hiring a professional for the job?

Comment: @Capsule, are you that person?

Comment: No, I already have a full time job. We have a client referral reward system but the minimum budget is usually around 50K :-)